# Show that a uniformly continuous function on $[0, 1)$ must be bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Suppose that $f: [0, 1) \to \Bbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous. Show that there exists $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for every $i \in$ {$1, 2, ..., N$} and every $x, y \in [\frac{i-1}{N}, \frac{i}{N}), |f(x) - f(y)| < 1$.

And thus show that a uniformly continuous function on $[0, 1)$ must be bounded.

Comment: For the second part, $f(x) < f(\frac{N-1}{N})+1$ for each $x \in [\frac{N-1}{N},1)$ and $f$ is continuous on the compact $[0,\frac{N-1}{N}]$

Comment: The simplest way to conclude the function is bounded is to show that uniformly continuous functions preserve Cauchy sequences, and hence that $\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x)$ must exist.

Comment: I'd say my way is simpler

Comment: @TheoBendit 's is the first thing coming to mind for me. The title just shouts for you to apply the extreme value theorem.

Comment: Uniformly continuous function can be extended continuously to the end point 1. So you get compact set

Answer (score 5):

By the definition of uniform continuity, applied with $\epsilon=1$, there's some $\delta>0$ such that changing the value of $x$ by less than $\delta$ results in changing the value of $f(x)$ by less than $1$. Fix a positive integer $N>1/\delta$. You can go from 0 to any point in $[0,1)$ in at most $N$ steps, each of length $\leq 1/N<\delta$. As you take these $N$ or fewer steps, $f(x)$ changes by less than $1$ at each step and therefore by $<N$ altogether. Therefore, at any point in $[0,1)$, the value of $f(x)$ is less than $f(0)+N$ and greater than $f(0)-N$. So $f$ is bounded on $[0,1)$.

Comment: So to show $|f(x) - f(y)| < 1$ I just use the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous and apply $\epsilon = 1$? Also, I kind of understand your reasoning but is there a rigorous way to write it? Thanks.

Comment: @EtherealMist of course there is a rigorous way to write it. you should try to write it yourself